# Firestore timestamp for client sdk

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Did something change or am I doing something incorrect? This is not working for me:

`createdOn: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

App initialization looks like this:

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
firestore.settings(settings);
```

And after using the above method to set a server timestamp, my data looks like this in Firestore:

```
createdOn:
  methodName: "FieldValue.serverTimestamp"
```

Whereas the Node SDK sets the timestamp as a timestamp object correctly when utilized.

**Edit**

This is the code that writes the timestamp:

```
const get_audit_data = (user) => {
  return {
    createdBy: {
      id: user.uid,
      name: {
        first: user.name.first,
        last: user.name.last,
      },
    },
    createdOn: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full code that actually writes the timestamp, not just a line of it.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated

Comment: That code just defines and returns an object, but doesn't do anything with Firestore.  What exactly are you doing to write to the database?

Comment: @DougStevenson, your question just stimulated a thought. The data in my post is actually being sent to a HTTP cloud function, which then performs the write via the Firestore admin SDK. Perhaps that is the issue, i.e. using the client SDK to create the timestamp while the admin SDK is the one that writes it. I can post all the code involved in that process, but the gist is that the object seen above is posted to an HTTP route, then is set in Firestore via a `transaction.set()` operation. I.e. `transaction.set('path', data);`

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the server timestamp token returned by `serverTimestamp()` is going to work like that.  If you're not using it along with a write from the client SDK, who knows how it'll be misinterpreted.  Maybe put your own special token in there, and replace it on the server with the admin SDK's version of serverTimestamp()?

Comment: Yep, I'm going to just add the timestamp server-less side and will report back findings.

Comment: @DougStevenson confirmed that was the issue. Thanks for the insightful question!